# Delphi TNotificationCenter Multiple Repeating Notifications has unexpected behaviour

Tags: android, delphi, notifications, firemonkey

lets say you want to create a Notification with a repeat interval so that it is recurring

```
var
    MyNotification : TNotification;
begin
    MyNotification := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;
    try
        MyNotification.Name := 'FirstNotification';
        MyNotification.AlertBody := 'First Notification!';
        MyNotification.FireDate := IncSecond(Now,15);// Note this fires 15 secs from NOW
        MyNotification.RepeatInterval := TRepeatInterval.Minute;
        Notificationcenter1.ScheduleNotification(MyNotification);
    finally
        MyNotification.DisposeOf;
    end;
```

In my case it is recurring to remind the user to respond to the notification, and then Once the user responds to the Notification on the TNotificationCenters `OnReceiveLocalNotification` I simply cancel the notification

```
NotificationCenter1.CancelNotification(ANotification.Name);
```

this cancels the notification and it works(kind of)

Now the above example will create a notification and once every minute if it is not responded to it will fire again, and again till responded to.

But the problem now is if I would to create another notification that I also want to repeat:

```
var
    MyNotification2 : TNotification;
begin
    MyNotification2 := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;
    try
        MyNotification2.Name := 'SecondNotification';
        MyNotification2.AlertBody := 'Second Notification!';
        MyNotification2.FireDate := IncSecond(Now,30);// Note this fires 30 secs from NOW
        MyNotification2.RepeatInterval := TRepeatInterval.Minute;
        Notificationcenter1.ScheduleNotification(MyNotification2);
    finally
        MyNotification2.DisposeOf;
    end;
```

if the Second Notification's FireDate is set to later than the first then it all works fine and dandy as expected, BUT if I was to Create the Second Notification with a FireDate like `IncSecond(Now,10)` meaning it will fire before the first scheduled Notification things go wrong

```
var
    MyNotification2 : TNotification;
begin
    MyNotification2 := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;
    try
        MyNotification2.Name := 'SecondNotification';
        MyNotification2.AlertBody := 'Second Notification!';
        MyNotification2.FireDate := IncSecond(Now,10);// Note this fires 10 secs from NOW
        MyNotification2.RepeatInterval := TRepeatInterval.Minute;
        Notificationcenter1.ScheduleNotification(MyNotification2);
    finally
        MyNotification2.DisposeOf;
    end;
```

The First Notification **never arrives** and the second Notification is no longer removed by `NotificationCenter1.CancelNotification(ANotification.Name);`
the `CancelNotification` will now have no effect on the SecondNotification

**Update 1**

I can confirm that the code works exactly as it should (No unexpected behaviour) in iOS so this is a Android related issue,

I have tried it on Xperia Z2 running 5.0.2 and a Samsung Note 2 running 4.4.2 and the behaviour is exactly the same

Comment: try this solution - not sure if its the same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906638/delphi-seattle-android-tnotificationcenter-cancelall-not-working